# about datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that I want to add the content of the datagridview to a listbox every time I double clik on the cell of the datagridview, then store the contents of the listbox in my database. please help.

Comment: Are you asking for a complete solution, or do you partly understand how you have to approach your problem? At what point are you uncertain?

Comment: Do you have any code written already? What kind of Database are you using? Is this WPF, WinForms, SilverLight? What version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use the cellclick event off the datagridview, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx

Then implement a "system"(session or something) that keeps track of the clicks when the amount of clicks = 2, add the cell value to your listbox and reset the counter to 0.

When do you want the storing of the contents in the listbox to occure?

Comment: after selecting the number of items needed, for example 20